# Knockout and JSTree not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jstree

I am using KnockoutJS on my page and trying to populate the DOM for a JsTree, but the JsTree is not identifying the leaves correctly and applying any changes to the code of the leaves(or folders) that KnockoutJs populates.  Is there a way to tell JsTree that there is new data and should re-evaluate everything?
Script at beginning of page

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        function treeNode(data) {
            var self = this;
            self.id = ko.observable(data.ID);
            self.name = ko.observable(data.Name);
        }

        function partsViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.partTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.selectedPartType = ko.observable();
            self.selectedPartType = ko.observable();

            $.getJSON("/PartKO/PartTypes", function(allData) {
                var mappedPartTypes = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new treeNode(item); });
                self.partTypes(mappedPartTypes);
            });

            $("#navigation").jstree({
                "themes": { "theme": "classic" },
                "plugins": ["themes", "html_data"]
            });
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new partsViewModel());

    });
```

HTML

```
ul id="navigation" class="treeview" data-bind="foreach: partTypes">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-bind="text:name"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `.jstree` after the list is populated, so move the call to the end of the `$.getJSON` callback.

Also the `navigation` should be a container containing the `<ul>` element and not the list itself.

Change `partsViewModel` function to:

```
function partsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.partTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedPartType = ko.observable();
    self.selectedPartType = ko.observable();

    $.getJSON("/PartKO/PartTypes", function(allData) {
      var mappedPartTypes = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new treeNode(item); });
      self.partTypes(mappedPartTypes);

      $("#navigation").jstree({
        "themes": { "theme": "classic" },
        "plugins": ["themes", "html_data"]
      });
    });
}
```

And your HTML to:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="treeview" data-bind="foreach: partTypes">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text:name"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/3LqhP/)** is a simplified example.

**Update:**

If you want to update the tree everytime the `<ul>` is changed you can use Knockout's [`.afterRender`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) callback. This will be called after the DOM is updated. You cannot use [`.subscribe()`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) because that is called before the DOM changes.

Insert this into `partsViewModel` and remove the `.jstree` part from `.getJSON` callback:

```
    self.redrawTree = function() {
        $("#navigation").jstree({
            "themes": {
                "theme": "classic"
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "html_data"]
        });
    };
```

And change HTML to:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul class="treeview" data-bind="foreach: { data: partTypes, afterRender: redrawTree }">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-bind="text:name"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same rendering error where no folders are showing up after implementing your code.  I checked out the JSFiddle and the only thing that is different that I can tell is that you are using the echo function instead of a normal JSON.  I'm not sure if that could make the difference.  Is there any way that you know of to have the jstree after every time the partTypes koObservable is updated?

Comment: @PITaylor Using `echo` service instead of `/PartKO/PartTypes` shouldn't make a difference. I recommend to insert a `console.log` into the `.getJSON()` callback or use the debugger and check if the data are retrieved and processed correctly. You can also remove the `.jstree` call and only check if the `<ul>` is generated properly. I also updated my answer with information about updating jstree after changes in `partTypes`.

Comment: If I remove the the .jstree the formatting stays the same.  I do have the full list still.  I like where you are going with the afterRender, but when I add that into the code it eliminates all my <li> items except for the first one.

Comment: Scratch that last comment. I made a dumb error while testing it out and it works beautifully.

Comment: @PITaylor EDIT: Glad it works now! I already prepared another example for you - **[here it is](http://jsbin.com/arugiz/edit#javascript,live)** :).

Comment: Sidenote:do you know why that doesn't appear to work in JsFiddle?

Comment: @PITaylor: I'm not aware that it doesn't work with JsFiddle. I'm unable to access the JsFiddle from work but JSBin is working. I will test it at home and let you know.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6389/discussion-between-pltaylor-and-dzejkej)